# Running into webpack issue with new version of react

Tags: reactjs

[image: image shows error of missing modules from webpack]

i have followed the directions and it has not solved the error. I have no other ideas how to solve this issue. I believe it would be fixed with a react app of version 4.0.3 but im not sure how id make that happen either. I have tried installing https browserify, and zlib, and browserify zlib, and ive tried creating a webpack.global.js file in the projet to add the fallback and still. No success.

````
{
  "name": "self-improvement",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "ansi-html-community": "^0.0.8",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "discord-oauth2": "^2.12.0",
    "eris": "^0.17.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zlib": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "url": "^0.11.3"
  },
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The library [`discord-oauth2`](https://github.com/reboxer/discord-oauth2) that you are trying to use is meant to be used in Node.js, not in a browser (confirmed by the repo's owner [here](https://github.com/reboxer/discord-oauth2/issues/86#issuecomment-1288365605) and [here](https://github.com/reboxer/discord-oauth2/issues/48#issuecomment-800489847)).

Fixing the error you get would only make sense if you were using webpack to compile Node.js code on server-side, and so you would need to set the correct [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) for node environment.

Comment: Then how am i able to use it in nextjs? Its an issue when importing the library to react in the newest version. Version >5.

Comment: @JohnNagy You can only use this library on a server, not on React.

Comment: I literally have it working on a client side render on nextjs. If not then whats the solution / correct package for react?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to find that yourself, I've never needed to use such a library.